# Czech characters not showing correctly UTF8 encoded page

Tags: database, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

A section of our website uses a database table called 'description'. Its collation value is set in the database as 'utf8_czech_ci' (and type as 'VARCHAR') and the PHP itself is set to utf8 too. The title and other content written outside of the description area is rendered using the Czech alphabet. It shows � for Czech specific letters when drawing content from the description table.

For example, original text in the database from an input form on the site:

```
...naší skladbu níže...
```

Is output as:

```
...na�� skladbu n��e...
```

Can you think of anything I may have missed for the page to show Czech characters correctly?

Comment: How was the data in the table populated in the first place?

Comment: Did you use "set names utf8" for MySQL?

Comment: Looks like you have non-UTF-8 data that you're trying to display as UTF-8 data. How are you verifying that the data in the database is encoded correctly?

Comment: OK, I did a little digging upon Arvo's suggestion and added this line to our PHP database connection code:

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Thanks Arvo!